# Magento 2 - bin/magento Commands not working in Cpanel Terminal

Tags: magento2, command-line, file-permissions

I have an issue while try to run commands bin/magento in terminal. Commands not working. No command run after bin directory. You can see the below screenshot about the error.

Basically yesterday I installed Mailchimp extension using SSH Putty (login as root user). Now I can't run commands in terminal.

[image]

Need help.

Comment: Try sudo magento c:f.

Comment: sudo magento cache:flush. not working, showing  "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?"

Answer (score 1):

You need to run magento2 ssh command from root of the magento. Goto directory **public_html** (not goto **bin** directory) and run

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

To reset all file and folder permission

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Change permission of these three directory & files to 755 or 777.

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`public_html/bin`** and change permission to **`775`**

Comment: Tried. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it inside the magento root project.

inside `public_html` not in `public_html/bin/`

Answer (score -1):

Give permission to `generated` Directory

```
chmod 755 -R generated
```

GIve appropriate permission to generated directory.

Comment: Friends **don't** let friends **777**.